# Wordpress/Woocommerce User Registration in Steps

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, registration

I have come across a client request that requires me to design woocommerce user registration in different steps. Since i am new to woocommerce i need your help on this please. Here is how the client wants it.

1. **STEP 1:** This step will happen on the "*My Account*" page that contains Sign In and Sign Up form both. Here the Sign Up form should have only two fields that is Username and Email.
2. **STEP 2:** From step 1 after validation, the user should be send to Step 2 where all the other fields should be asked from User. Others fields can include *First Name, Last Name, Address, Password* etc.
3. **STEP 3:** After Step 2a confirmation email should be sent to User and upon putting right code he/she can become a sucessfull member.

Now if there is a plugin that can do this let me know otherwise i prefer coding it. Kindly help me out here guys as i have always got what i am looking for on stackoverflow.

Regards,

Maddy

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom code there is no plugin available for the same.

1) Create custom template for register.
2) After fillip both data you just need to call user resgietr function https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user

Comment: Can you please send me a link where it is shown the custom template creation for register? As i said i have mostly done theme customizations on wordpress and is new to getting all of this done. It would be really appreciated.

Comment: First Name , Last Name and Address will be given by the user when he does checkout after buying an item and that detail is available in usermeta table so i would suggest not asking these details after register..

Comment: Brother your suggestion is valid but when it comes to client we have to deliver what is being asked. And this specific client wouldn't take suggestions lightly :) So any tutorial that help me with Template creation for register? Please let me know?